# Laravel package unit testing failing for helper function in config file (call to undefined method base_path())

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5.3

Okay, So I'm trying to update a package that I used a good deal with Laravel 4 to be compatible with Laravel 5, since the original repository hasn't had any updates for a while and it needed a few tweaks to work with Laravel 5.

I have made the necessary changes, and created a [pull request](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/polyglot/pull/55) to the original repository.

I noticed the unit tests had failed, though, so I tried digging into it. I haven't done anything with PHPUnit so far, so I figured this would be a good learning experience.

I'm not asking for help with the error displayed on github. I managed to get past that error, but I achieved this by removing some tests, which of course isn't an actual solution, thus these changes are not committed. I will fix that once I have a better understanding of how unit testing works.

The problem I seem to be having is that one of Laravel's helper functions is being used in the default config file of the package, it is saying the function `base_path()` is undefined.

As I understand, PHPUnit works with classes and I would need to mock the function in order for it to be used. Can't seem to find a straight answer HOW to do that.

Since it's pointing a config variable to a folder which doesn't exist in my repository hierarchy, I'm not even sure what it should return.

The file that's causing the issue is the default config located in polyglot/config/polyglot.php

```
return [

// Whether to swap out the facades (Router, Lang, etc) with
// Polyglot's, disable this if you need other packages to do the same
// Can specify an array of facades to swap, eg. ['Lang', 'URL']
'facades' => true,

// Locales
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The default locale if none is provided in the URL
// Leave empty to force the use of locales prefixes in URLs
'default' => 'en',

// The fallback locale for translations
// If null, the default locale is used
'fallback' => null,

// The available locales
'locales' => [],

// Gettext
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The domain of your translations, for gettext use
'domain' => 'messages',

// Where the PO/MO files reside

'folder' => base_path('resources/lang'),
// Format of the compiled files
'file' => '{domain}.po',

// Database
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The pattern Polyglot should follow to find the Lang classes
// Examples are "Lang\{model}", "{model}Lang", where {model}
// will be replaced by the model's name
'model_pattern' => '{model}Lang',
```

];

So, what is typical to do in this situation? Define the function manually? Include the helper file somehow? Or discard the use of the function and go with a solution using basic php directory references? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code, please? Like: the code calling `base_path`, the PHPUnit test that's exploding, the PHPUnit configuration, and so on.

Comment: All 27 tests are failing because of this. I'm not sure what you mean by configuration, but the version is 4.8. I didn't write the tests originally, have only a slight clue how they even work. You can find the whole package here https://github.com/Anahkiasen/polyglot (develop branch) I also linked to the pull request in the original question.

Comment: [`base_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-base-path) is a standard Laravel helper. It's available every time Laravel boots. The proper thing to do is to boot Laravel in your tests (by using the `TestCase` that comes with Laravel). Less proper is mocking it (which would be just `function base_path() { return __DIR__; }` or some such). Least proper would be using PHP file references and string assembly to build it.

Comment: Ah, this package is currently using the phpunit library directly, despite being dependant on laravel. I just found this article, I think it should be enough to get me started.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/guide-how-to-run-integration-tests-from-a-package

Thanks

Comment: I've wrapped these comments up into a cohesive answer. Please accept if this does in fact answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`base_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-base-path) is a standard Laravel helper. It's available every time Laravel boots. The proper approach is booting Laravel in your tests via the `TestCase` base class included in Laravel. Refer to the official [testing guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/testing) and [this laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/guide-how-to-run-integration-tests-from-a-package).

You should not mock the method. You should not replace it with file references and string assembly. Doing either of these moves the code *away* from Laravel integration, not toward, as you wanted to do with the L5 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else googling this, the solution I found was to use the `CreatesApplication` trait and call the `createApplication()` method in your test class.

```php
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
   use Tests\CreatesApplication;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->createApplication();
    }
}
```

After adding this to your class, you can then access helper classes like `app()` and `base_path()`, etc.